# Mule string concatenation of escape characters

Tags: syntax, mule, mel

Lets assume that emp-no has the value of 12345

I want to create a SQL query at runtime that will change

```
select * from emp where emp_no = '#[flowVars['emp-no']]'
```

to

> select * from emp where emp_no = '12345'

What is the correct MEL syntax as I have to many ' in my MEL. I have tried using the escape character but no luck.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Mule JDBC transport, you do not need to quote the column value, so the correct version is:

```
select * from emp where emp_no = #[flowVars['emp-no']]
```

If your flowVars['emp-no'] is numerical and you really need the quotes, set the flowVars['emp-no'] to type String instead.

If you are not using Mule JDBC, and just want to set the example payload, use:

```
<set-payload value="select * from emp where emp_no = '#[flowVars['emp-no']]'" />
```

Comment: Hi Anton. I now see that when I assign the string to a variable that in fact it is correct. I am getting an JDBC error when I run the flow. If I change the flowVars to a static value of '12345' it works. But when I want to use the emp-no value that I get from the URL I get this error 

    Invalid column index(SQL Code: 17003, SQL State: + 99999) (java.sql.SQLException)
      oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement:5377 (null)

So its seems I can not bind variables at runtime using this method.

Comment: What is the correct way then as all the samples show on getting values with out any where values in the SQL.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working using this link http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/jdbc-connector#undefined